# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined at new Router at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent WithoutOwner

Tags: reactjs, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I can't find any other mention of this error and I have try my best,I'm using `react-router`,... what could be the issue ?
Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
>       at new Router (eval at ./node_modules/react-router/es/Router.js (index.js:1), :36:52)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js
>   (index.js:1), :298:16)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js (index.js:1),
>   :285:19)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js (index.js:1),
>   :188:21)
>       at Object.mountComponent (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactReconciler.js (index.js:1),
>   :46:35)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js (index.js:1),
>   :371:34)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js (index.js:1),
>   :258:21)
>       at Object.mountComponent (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactReconciler.js (index.js:1),
>   :46:35)
>       at mountComponentIntoNode (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js (index.js:1),
>   :104:32)
>       at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (eval at ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/Transaction.js (index.js:1),
>   :140:20)

Comment: when I locate the error,it always blink around here(...,{"use strict";......)

Answer (score 1):

what's your react-router version?
V3.0 is working fine but
react-router V4.0 Can't use that
 `import { hashHistory } from 'react-router'`

try this 
 `import {Route, BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';`

Comment: mine is "react-router-dom": "~4.0.0"

Comment: Yes, you can use 3.0 or import another dependency of react-router-dom